# Applying a specific schema on an Apache Spark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to apply a particular schema on a dataframe , the schema seems to have been applied but all dataframe operations like count, show, etc. always fails with `NullPointerException` as shown below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference.hashCode(namedExpressions.scala:218)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.hash(ScalaRunTime.scala:210)
```

Here is my code:

```
var fieldSchema = ListBuffer[StructField]()
val columns = mydf.columns

 for (i <- 0 until columns.length) {
      val columns = mydf.columns
      val colName = columns(i)
      fieldSchema += StructField(colName, mydf.schema(i).dataType, true, null)
    }
 val schema = StructType(fieldSchema.toList)
 val newdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema) << df is the original dataframe
 newdf.printSchema() << this prints the new applied schema
 println("newdf count:"+newdf.count()) << this fails with null pointer exception
```

In short,there are actually 3 dataframes:

1. df - the original data frame
2. mydf- the schema that I'm trying to apply on df is coming from this dataframe
3. newdf- creating a new dataframe same as that of df, but with different schema

Comment: you are creating same dataframe with such complexity, why? And the code passes without error. So can you update your derivation of mydf?

Comment: there are actually 3 data frames 1. df - the original data frame 2.mydf- the schema that I'm trying to apply on df is coming from this dataframe 3.newdf- creating a new dataframe same as that of df, but with different schema

Comment: ok :) can you also update the question with derivation of df and mydf?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but I'm almost sure you are making unnecessary stuff.

Comment: What's the version of Spark?

Comment: its spark version-1.6